# How to make persistant usb drive using Ubuntu 17.10 gnome

Tags: boot, gnome, usb, live-usb

Lots of research, tries and frustration and I am still unable to make a "persistent" live usb in Ubuntu 17.10. Using a 64 GB usb3 stick and ubuntu 17.10 gnome. I have tried to run different softwares in both wayland and xorg as suggested on various web sites with no luck. Looking at some of the cli suggestions leave me really confused and fearful to even try especially as some of them had bad reviews.  I can make a live disk with no problem. Any help?

Comment: the easiest way is to just create the default live-install-media on one usb or dvd, then 'install' it to another usb thumb-drive (ie. your 64gb one).  this method is dead easy. once done you only keep the 'installed' one as the first 'live' isn't needed. it does require two thumb-drives (or one + dvdr; or one plus iso on hdd/sdd and modified grub to allow its boot etc)

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try tomorrow. Difference is media to media not pc to media, I believe this will work. Let you know.

Comment: Did not work. Broke grub on the PC and the USB stick was not bootable. Thought I did everything correctly when assigning partitions etc.. Oh well, I have given it a good go.

Comment: a very common mistake is writing grub to the wrong place.  it should be written to the device as your bios doesn't know about partitions, only drives/devices & sectors. you didn't specify a partition [for grub] did you?   However if your intended machine is using EUFI you have to do everything thru bios as the MBR is ignored.

Comment: Ah the light hits - EUFI. I did indeed specify a grub partition and a / and a data and verified it with gparted. The install diaog is pretty clear on that. That does not explain why the pc grub got broken however.